# No Properties, Result from autocomplete input text php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I'm not understand why the query is not working, if i try using localhost is work fine but using "mysql" and i try to use PDO in my website and not give a result. and i try to look the error_log i a get error like this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in fungsi/f_record.php on line 9
```

This my source
f_record.php

```
<?php
include "../config/c_config.php";
$db = dbConn::getConnection();

$uq = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
$return = array();
$sqlac= "SELECT * FROM str_user WHERE name LIKE '$uq'";
$resac = $db->query($sqlac);
while($resac = $sqlac->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    array_push($return,array('label'=>$resac['name'],'value'=>$resac['name']));
    }
    echo(json_encode($return));
?>
```

and index.php

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#txtname" ).autocomplete({
            source: "f_record.php",
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>


<div>
    <label for="Name">Name: </label>
    <input id="txtname" class="txtname"/>
</div>
```

how to fix this..

Comment: post your `f_autocomplete_cust.php`

Comment: dose your PHP version on server support PDO ?

Comment: @SO-user : sory, i edit that..mistakenly written

Comment: @jQuery : yes, support..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

**Read the error message carefully.**

Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

There is one call to `fetch()` in your code. It is `$sqlac->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

`$sqlac` is a string. You can't call `fetch` on a `string` because it isn't an `object`.

This is covered in the [PHP reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983).

Answer (score 0):

First create the db handle properly, I am not sure "$db" how it gets created in your code sine you have not mentioned code for dbconn::getconnection(). I have replaced it with $dbh.

```
    <?php
    include "../config/c_config.php";
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();
    *$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);*

    $uq = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
    $return = array();
    $sqlac = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM str_user WHERE name LIKE '$uq'");
    $sqlac->execute();

    while($resac = $sqlac->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        array_push($return,array('label'=>$resac['name'],'value'=>$resac['name']));
        }
        echo(json_encode($return));
    ?>
```